# How to remove iTunes DRM on Mac?

Tags: itunes, drm

I want to play some purchased/rental videos/songs from iTunes on Samsung Galaxy S6, but the DRM makes it no way to access to those videos/music. So I got to find a way to remove DRM from iTunes videos. I use Mac. Any suggestion?

Comment: You want help to violate your contract with Apple, and, in some jurisdictions, commit a crime?

Comment: Not really. I just want to have it for personal use, no share no uploading. You know for my other devices, not only for apple products. Or I have to buy another iPhone. I just wonder if there's such program available.

Comment: It _is_ a violation of your agreement with Apple, and, _in some jurisdictions_, it _is_ a crime. I guess when you give your word in a contract, it doesn't mean anything.

Comment: Ok, if it is crime, then I'd better quit. Anyway, I will find another way out without this DRM removal behave.

Answer (score 1):

Apple removed the mandatory DRM from iTunes a few years ago, though any songs you have from before that time will still have the DRM.

You can quite legitimately remove it like this…

**Delete Old DRM Copies of iTunes Music and Download DRM-Free Versions**

If you purchased any music from iTunes between 2003 and 2009, you downloaded tracks with DRM ([Digital Rights Management](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digital_rights_management)) in them. Apple's long since removed the DRM, but you might not have. Wired shows how to update your music library with the new, DRM-free versions.

The process here is pretty simple, but if you're anything like me, you never bothered to actually do it:

- Before starting, make sure you are signed in to the iTunes Store [Store menu] & can see the columns for **Kind** & **iCloud Download** in your **Songs** view in iTunes, then sort by **Kind**
  Scroll down to find 'Protected AAC audio file' as a Kind - those are the ones you need to replace.

[image: iTunes]

1. In iTunes, select iTunes > Preferences and click the "Store tab"
2. Make sure "Show iTunes in the Cloud Purchases" is checked and close the Preferences panel
3. Click on the cloud icon in your list view and make sure all your purchases are there (note which songs are here and do not delete anything in step 5 that isn't available for download)
4. Now, delete the old DRM versions by sorting by "Kind" in the list view (if it's not there, go to View > Show View Options and select it)
5. Scroll down to see if any tracks are listed as "Protected AAC audio file." That's the DRM music you need to replace. If you can download it again from iTunes with the cloud icon, you can delete the DRMed version

Once you run through the process of deleting those songs you can download them from the cloud at any point, DRM free. This has been around for a while, but if you haven't grabbed those DRM free versions, now's as good a time as any.

Source: Lifehacker [Delete Old DRM Copies of iTunes Music and Download DRM-Free Versions](http://lifehacker.com/delete-old-drm-copies-of-itunes-music-and-download-drm-1546445214)

Also see - [Which songs in my iTunes library are DRM protected?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/2482/which-songs-in-my-itunes-library-are-drm-protected?rq=1)

The same does not apply to video content, only audio.